# Red5 Server fails to start

Tags: java, ubuntu, red5, rtmp

i have  a problem when starting my Red5 Server on Ubuntu 12.04. 
When i'm trying to start it up, it doesn't work properly and show some error message like this :

root@PC:/usr/share/red5# ./red5.sh

Running on  Linux

Starting Red5

Red5 root: /usr/share/red5

Configuation root: /usr/share/red5/conf

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "147ss"

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)

at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)

at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.scrubURLList(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:505)

at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.build(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:179)

at org.red5.classloading.ClassLoaderBuilder.build(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:97)

at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:126)

at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:50)
```

That's all the error message i've got.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem because of there is a extra string in a jar file with in your red5 lib directory.

Goto lib directory of your red5 and remove ss from bcprov jar file

> mv bcprov-jdk15on-1.47*.jar bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar

Then start server.